# Does iPhone 4 work with Bluetooth Headphones/Headsets that have Back/Next/Answer?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I am considering purchasing something like [Sennheiser MM450 Bluetooth Headphones](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/home_en.nsf/root/private_headsets_mobile_music_502891) but I'd like to get some input on whether the Back/Next/Play/Pause/Answer buttons work as expected with iPhone 4?

I've seen some old reviews that said not, but nothing about iPhone 4 / iOS 4.x..

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The iPhone 4 has Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR wireless technology meaning it supports stereo audio and controls. Personally I have [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BHCSQC) and they have answer/volume +/-/ skip/back/play/pause buttons that all work with iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

Older iOS versions had an extremely finicky Bluetooth AVRCP implementation, but since iOS 3 it works reliably with many more devices.  The Motorola S9-HD is one of the devices which didn't work well with older iOS, as attested by many reviews; I have one, and while it was indeed flaky under iOS 2, it's been solid ever since iOS 3 came out.